# Node Sequelize with sqlcipher SQLITE_NOMEM error

Tags: node.js, sqlite, sequelize.js, sqlcipher

I am getting an out of memory error whenever I try to update records with Sequelize and sqlcipher in my node project.

I can connect and fetch from my database without an issue but when I try to update I always get this error:

```
name: 'SequelizeDatabaseError',
parent: [Error: SQLITE_NOMEM: out of memory]
```

The query that is attempting to run is a basic update by primary key id query. There are only 80 records in the table. There is one other table with about ~400 record but the total file size of the db is only 400kb

```
'UPDATE `Phones` SET `deviceUuid`=$1,`userId`=$2,`updatedAt`=$3 WHERE `id` = $4'
```

I have tried the following:

- Setting `--max-old-space-size` flag when running node.
- Setting `PRAGMA cache_size` for sqlite.
- Using sequelize `sync()` to create and build a fresh database to make sure it matches my models exactly and there's nothing weird going on with my db file.
- Changing the update to try to update a single field.
- I have examined my code for potential memory leaks

The project is running on node 16.16.0 with the following packages

- @journeyapps/sqlcipher@5.3.1
- sequelize@6.31.0